# How to open an html page from razor page

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have this ASP.NET Core MVC project:

[image]

I want to open the HTML element (html page) named `Impresorashtml.html` from `Index.cshtml` using

```
<a href="/Impresorashtml.html" target="_blank"> Impresoras </a>
```

The page opens, but I get an error:

> This localhost page can't be found

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Razor Pages Project. Any way, no matter Razor Pages or MVC project, the static file should be located in the `wwwroot` folder **by default**. Then you could easily access it.

1. If you place the `Impresorashtml.html` in the root of the `wwwroot` folder. You can access it by using code below:

   ```
   <a href="/Impresorashtml.html" target="_blank"> Impresoras </a>
   ```

   [image]
2. If you place the `Impresorashtml.html` in the sub folder of the `wwwroot` folder. You can access it by using code like below:

   ```
   <a href="/html/Impresorashtml.html" target="_blank"> Impresoras </a>
   ```

   [image]

If you want to **serve files outside** of `wwwroot` like what you did(place it in the `Pages` folder), you need configure the static file middleware as follows:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Pages")),
    RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
});
```

Then access it by using the code below:

```
<a href="/StaticFiles/Impresorashtml.html" target="_blank"> Impresorashtml</a>
```

Reference:

[Serve files outside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root)

Comment: Thanks. Should I move the html element (the page file) using the solution explorer in Visual Studio? Or should I move using the Windows folders (Windows explorer)?

Comment: Hi @Emmanuel_InfTech, pls check my answer carefully, I also share another solution if you do not want to move the html file to the wwwroot, just add the middleware and change your `href` of anchor link.